# SSRS F(X) expression trying to get previous year in IIF condition

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have a dashboard created in SSRS ,where i show sales statistics .There is a parameter called rpYear that has labels and values as Year(Today),Year(Today)-1,Year(Today-2) and ALL.The value of ALL is ''.So if user selects all in drop down i show sales statistics of all years by excluding year in query.There is a report where i need to show sale in selected year and previous year,in case all is selected it should show current year and current year -1 .For this i created a parameter
as rpPrevYear with expression

```
=IIF(Parameters!rpYear.Value <> "",Parameters!rpYear.Value-1,Year(Today)-1)
```

However i get the error "input string is not in correct format"

The issue is here Parameters!rpYear.Value-1 if i remove -1 ,the reports generate.I tried using CInt(Parameters!rpYear.Value)-1 but still i get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your Year parameter is a string so when you try to subtract 1, there would be an error about the string. When you use CINT to Convert to an Integer, it will give an error when trying to convert the empty string to an integer.

One solution is to change the parameter to an integer and use 0 for all.

You can also change your parameter to use multiple selections but then you'd need to change your parameter evaluation.

Comment: It is working ,when i made it 0.Thank you